# .NET Save Configuration Settings to PerUserRoaming Location

Tags: .net, vb.net, configuration-files, roaming-profile

I have a VS2010 solution with a Settings.settings file. The user settings are saved to the Local Settings folder and this is a problem as these settings do not roam.

Currently the settings file is saved automatically to:

```
Dim config_initial As System.Configuration.Configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal)
Console.WriteLine("Local user config path: {0}", config_initial.FilePath)
```

( `C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Local Settings\Application Data\%company%\%application%.exe_Url_%hash%\%version%\user.config` )

Is there any way to save this file to the file path identified by:

```
Dim config_new As System.Configuration.Configuration = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming)
Console.WriteLine("User config path: {0}", config_new.FilePath)
```

( `C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\%company%\%application%.exe_Url_%hash%\%version%\user.config` )

I am just saving using `My.Settings.Save()` or automatically when the application terminates at the moment.

Comment: This is a function of the roaming profiles.  If you did this, your users settings for this app would not move with them from workstation to workstation.  Is this a consequence that you are comfortable with?

Comment: When proof reading I didn't notice that I had it round the wrong way. Currently it does not roam and I want the application settings to roam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://blog.gfader.com/2007/01/roaming-user-config-file-important-on.html). In Visual Studio, open the Application Settings screen, then select an individual setting, and then go to the Properties Window. There is then an option to set `Roaming` to `True`

[image]